# consolidate vba excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function, range

I'm trying to create a macro in order to consolidate data from two columns, but it didn't work and I cannot understand why.

I have two columns A (column1) and B (column2), which contain data until cell 5.
I also want to include the titles written in cell 1 in both columns.
How should I write my array in the function consolidate?

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Consolidate _
    Sources:=Array("Sheet1!R1C1:R5C3", "Sheet1!R1C2:R5C2"), _
    Function:=xlSum, _ TopRow:=True, _ LeftColumn:=True
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? `Sources:=Array("Sheet1!R1C1:R5C2"`) sounds like the range you want, but I'm not sure it gives the result you want.

Comment: The source should be: Sources:=Array("Sheet1!R1C1:R5C1", "Sheet1!R1C2:R5C2")

Comment: That should probably be Sources:=Array(Range("Sheet1!R1C1:R5C1") , Range("Sheet1!R1C2:R5C2")). Not sure cause I'm on phone.